# Debian web server inaccessible after moving VM

Tags: debian

I have a dev laptop with Debian + LAMP as the dev env. We are using virtualbox and there are 2 network adapters : NAT and VB Host Only.

I copied the VHD over to my desktop and setup the VM using the VHD and added NAT and VB Host only adapters to the VM in the VirtualBox interface.

However when I boot up the VM I can no longer access the website on 192.168.56.101

On Firefox there is a weird message saying "the connection has been reset" but I don't know how to fix this. Is this a DNS cache problem?

Comment: What is your host system? Also Debian?

Comment: @Anthon no it was Windows

Comment: Then that is probably the cause. I have never seen this on Linux in VirtualBox on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox's "host only" adapter is really buggy and randomly fails in the way you describe.

The workaround is to use VirtualBox's bridged interface, or, if feasible, use VMWare Player (or, if you have the cash, VMware Workstation, or a dedicated server running OpenVZ or another more reliable virtualization technology) instead.

I once posted a blog with a possible registry edit which seems to help, but this is an incomplete fix and doesn't completely solve the problem:

http://samiam.org/blog/20130826.html

Other workarounds include rebooting both the Windows host and the guest OS when the VirtualBox host-only adapter starts acting up.  Indeed, my host-only adapter works right now, but who knows when it will fail again.

Comment: Ok I was expecting someone to tell me "dude you forgot this, it was so obvious" kind of answer. Never knew host only is buggy and will definitely setup in bridged adapter if possible next time. Thanks